# How to replace multiple instances of a text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to prevent users to enter multiple empty paragraphs in the text editor and using the following approach I can remove a single `<p><br></p>` from the message text in the text editor.

```
var str = content.replace('<p><br></p>', '');
```

However, I need to remove all of the `<p><br></p>` parts like `<p><br></p><p><br></p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text<p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>`. Is there a smarter way e.g. regex or method to perform this in a single operation?

Comment: use regex to replace the content. content.replace(/<p><br><\/p>/g, "");

Comment: @GirishSasidharan Yes, I missed trailing `/` and end `/g` in my usage. Using `content.replace(/<p><br><\/p>/g, '')` fixed the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use regex to replace the content.

```
content.replace(/<p><br><\/p>/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

your `replace` will only remove exactly `'<p><br></p>'`.

Removing elements without content (or only whitespace content) using a proper DOM-method may be more successful. The snippet demonstrates that for some hypothetical elements in a mockup document body.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = `
  <p><br></p>
  <p>
   <br>
  </p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>
  <p>
  
   <br>
  
  </p>
  <p><br>        </p>
  <p><br></p>
  <p> <br>
    <p><br></p>
  </p>`;
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(el => {
  if (!el.textContent.trim()) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el)
  };
});
console.log(document.body.innerHTML.trim());
```

Comment: While I agree that if the user is concerned about any whitespace, then it may be better to convert to DOM and parse it that way (depends on OP's *actual* criteria). However, showing how to do it by overwriting the `document.body` appears counter-productive. If dealing with it as a DOM is the desired method, then it would be *much* better to convert with a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), particularly given that this is potentially untrusted content, which shouldn't be inserted into the page DOM.

Comment: The snippet is just a mockup. It is not telling the OP or anyone to overwrite the body, it was just a demonstration of using the DOM method to remove elements.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a regex or built-in functionality rather than using an iteration.

Comment: @MuratYıldız Have it your way. The snippet contains only build-in functionality.